# Changing longitude coordinates of shape file for plotting

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib-basemap

I am new to shape files.
I work in the Pacific ocean and often have dateline related problems.

Currently, I am able to plot half of the Longhurst provinces for the pacific
[longhurst shape file](https://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php#longhurst) downloaded from https://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=21483

Need to download the longhurst shapefile to longhurst/

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import geopandas as gp
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=120.,llcrnrlat=-40,urcrnrlon=290,urcrnrlat=40,
                resolution='l',projection='merc')
m.readshapefile('longhurst/Longhurst_world_v4_2010',name='longhurst')
```

Which produces something like this. I would like to do this for the whole Pacific. Not just the west:

[image: Broken province map]

I then discovered I can open the shape file with geopandas.
`provinces=gp.read_file('datasets/longhurst/')`

I am unable to work out how to modify the longitudes though. I just need to +360, or a more complicated  them I think and could plot both versions to get the extent accross the dateline. Any wisdom for this? Thanks.

In xarray the following works to shift the longitudes... But not sure how to apply to this case.

`dat= dat.assign_coords(lon=(dat.lon % 360)).roll(lon=dat.dims['lon']),roll_coords=False).sortby('lon')`

Comment: I've just answered a question that might be useful to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096171/geopandas-map-centering-the-country-on-the-plot-and-joining-its-split-geometri/65100389#65100389

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much. Interesting solution. I think I need to lon%360 to get the answer. Any way to do this with the ```moved_geom.append(translate(item, xoff=-180-shift))``` solution? Something like ```item%360```?

Comment: @Ocean_Scientist If it is a list/array, use numpy, i.e., `np.mod(list_of_lons, 360)`

Comment: I am not familar with shapely. I am lookng into it now. How can I get the lons from item / the Polygon? What can I replace the translate function with? Using this solution, would it be something like ```moved_geom.append(translate(item,xoff=np.mod(item.lons,360))```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates of the underlying shapely `POLYGONS` and `MULTIPOLYGON` (interestingly there is both) using, the command below.

```
provinces['geometry']
```

In geopandas the geometry is always stored in the `['geometry']` column. You could also use the build in method:

```
provinces.geometry
```

or for specific rows:

```
provinces.geometry[i]
```

Also look into the crs

```
provinces.crs
```

returns

```
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Maybe you could re-project from here using projection [managing tools of geopandas](https://geopandas.org/projections.html).

Comment: Ok thanks very much for this. This still doesn't get me any closer to the solution though. The re-projection looks real complicated. I wonder if there is a way to simply change the prime meridian .. ? In the geometry variable, I still cant work out any methods to modify the longitudes with modulo 360. Even just looking at the geometry object just prints the shape out which is cool but I just don't know how to work with this datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code I answered in another question to solve some of your problems (not possible to all). It is runnable (with certain shapefiles) and it produces the attached plot. I hope the code is useful for you to investigate further.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.affinity import translate

def shift_geom(shift, gdataframe, plotQ=False, extent=[-60,120, -50,40]):
    # shift: expect positive values for good results
    # crs: crs="EPSG:4326" (not anything else); this handles world geometries
    # this code is adapted from answer found in SO
    # will be credited here: ???
    shift -= 180
    moved_geom = []
    splitted_geom = []
    border = LineString([(shift,90),(shift,-90)])

    for row in gdataframe["geometry"]:
        splitted_geom.append(split(row, border))
    for element in splitted_geom:
        items = list(element)
        for item in items:
            minx, miny, maxx, maxy = item.bounds
            if minx >= shift:
                moved_geom.append(translate(item, xoff=-180-shift))
            else:
                moved_geom.append(translate(item, xoff=180-shift))

    # got `moved_geom` as the moved geometry
    # must specify CRS here
    moved_geom_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": moved_geom}, crs="EPSG:4326")

    # can change crs here
    if plotQ:
        #fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=[8,6])
        fig = plt.figure( figsize=(8,8) )
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot( projection=ccrs.PlateCarree() )
        moved_geom_gdf.plot( ax=ax1, figsize=(8,5), scheme='quantiles', cmap='tab20')
        ax1.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        # ax1.gridlines( draw_labels=True ) # careful, misleading labels
        plt.show()

    return moved_geom_gdf

wideseas = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file('./data/Longhurst_world_v4_2010.shp')
wideseas180 = shift_geom(180, wideseas, True, extent=[-60,120, -50,70])
```

The output plot:

[image: longhursplot]

Comment: And it's time to use `cartopy`.

Comment: Ok I think I need to spend more time on this and read into geopandas more. Thanks for your help. I'm not going to mark this as an answer though as I still havent got my use case working. Something to do with using basemap instead of cartopy maybe.

Comment: @OceanScientist The correct way to say `thanks` is upvoting or accept the answer. If the answer is not good enough, please give comments.