# Visualize area of Russia correctly

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, geopandas, shapefile

I should make specific map of Russia but I stucked on first step: I can't visualize the whole area correctly. For this I use that code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
path = 'C:\\Users\\sashk\\Python_projects\\Data_map_based\\data\\RUS_adm2.shp'
Map = gpd.read_file(path)
print(Map.shape)
Map.plot()
plt.show()
```

And so I get:

[image: Russia]

Please, if someone know how to fix it, help

Data structure:
[image: coords]

Comment: I am not sure that this is the best time to ask a question that involves the frontiers of Russia… That said, can't you roll the x coordinates with a modulo to have the <-150 data on the right?

Comment: @mozway I'm not involved in global processes, sorry. And I'm sure it's not the best place to discuss such things. I just need to solve this. How can I roll coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer and it's works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.affinity import translate
def shift_geom(shift, gdataframe, plotQ=False):
    shift -= 180
    moved_geom = []
    splitted_geom = []
    border = LineString([(shift,90),(shift,-90)])

    for row in gdataframe["geometry"]:
        splitted_geom.append(split(row, border))
    for element in splitted_geom:
        items = list(element)
        for item in items:
            minx, miny, maxx, maxy = item.bounds
            if minx >= shift:
                moved_geom.append(translate(item, xoff=-180-shift))
            else:
                moved_geom.append(translate(item, xoff=180-shift))

    # got `moved_geom` as the moved geometry            
    moved_geom_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": moved_geom})

    # can change crs here
    if plotQ:
        fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=[8,6])
        moved_geom_gdf.plot(ax=ax1)
        plt.show()

    return moved_geom_gdf

path = 'C:\\Users\\sashk\\Python_projects\\Data_map_based\\data\\RUS_adm2.shp'
Map = gpd.read_file(path)

# shift geometry of Russia
new_rus = shift_geom(90, Map, False)
# restore the geometry to original geo-location
# ... geometry now in 1 piece
# ... option True --> make a plot
_ = shift_geom(-90, new_rus, True)
```

Comment: I guess, you found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833670/geopandas-map-centering-with-countries/66894881#66894881

Comment: It was [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096171/geopandas-map-centering-the-country-on-the-plot-and-joining-its-split-geometri/65100389#65100389) Yes, I see, that it was you @swatchai. Thank you a lot!  Maybe you can suggest shorter way?